# Why single user can not login from two different browsers or system in flexi auth codeigniter?

Tags: php

I am using flexi auth codeigniter library in my one project. I have dont integration part. Now when I logined in user account from one browser and using same user credential I did logged in on another browser. When I logged in from another browser it logged me out from first browser. I dont know why it is happening. Please help me out to find the solution. I want to login from multiple browser with same user credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Flexi Auth but there is a config option `$config['security']['validate_login_onload']` set this to false and your problem is gone :D

I use personally CodeIgniter-[Aauth](https://github.com/emreakay/CodeIgniter-Aauth).